# Converted Universal App doesn't show the iPad Interface

Tags: ipad, ios-universal-app

At the moment I'm building an iPhone App.
Yesterday I tried to convert it to an Universal App.
It worked, but it just shows me the tab bar, but nothing else.
I've created some Web Views and a Table View, but the iPad Simulator didn't show anything, only the tab bar.
The iPhone Simulator works great, I can see all the labels, web views etc...
I've created one Storyboard for iPhone and one for iPad.

I don't know why the iPad Simulator doesn't display anything.

Hope you can help me.

Regards

Comment: how did you create the storyboard for the iPad? from scratch or by duplicating the iPhone storyboard?

Comment: new file -> user interface -> Storyboard -> iPad

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have changed the storyboard name in you target general settings, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Use the right name  for you app. Check also that the info.plist file for your project has been correctly updated:

[image]

(the second entry is for the iPad).

If that is ok, try and make a clean and rebuild.

Comment: I have two different Storyboards, MainStoryboard_iPhone and MainStoryboard_iPad. I've changed it already. It doesn't work...

Comment: Oh, but I forgot to say that I use one ViewController header and implementation file for iPhone and iPad...

Comment: are you doing anything specific to load the storyboard or just using what the default template does?

Comment: Mhmm...I think I'm just using what the default template does.... Sorry, but I'm new in Xcode..I've just created that second Storyboard and Changed the App to Universal, then I've changed my Info.plist and wrote the following: `Main storyboard file base name (iPad) = MainStoryboard_iPad`